# How to Sum record by Account Group in SAP Crystal Report

Tags: sql-server, vba, database, crystal-reports

I have report name "Trial Balance Detail", I have displayed the data that I need, then I want to add up this debit number based on the account group. but when I Sum on the Report Footer, the results actually match the records in detail. how can I add up the total records, but the records are based on group accounts

[image: example]

For example, 1,000,000 on debit it should show details on 3 row (ex. 500, 200, 300), but on that record, it's already the total per account

so I want the records that have become the total, added up based on the account that is displayed and entered into the report footer

example (but display is not detail)

[image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

Please try to explain the problem more clearly.